# C# SameSite flag issue

Tags: c#, google-chrome, httpcookie, samesite

As Chrome is going to make the `SameSite=None` and Secure flag mandatory from 80 version on 4th Feb, I am try to set this *flags* in my cookie using the following lines of code:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("XYZ");
myCookie.Value = newCookie;
myCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
myCookie.Secure = true;
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2);
context.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

But these properties are not working.
Even after upgrading the .Net Framework version to 4.8, this flag is not set the desired `SameSite=None` for the cookie.
Also one strange issue which i am facing is when i use the following line in web.config the flag correctly gets set in my cookie while requesting it from of the server:

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```

But when I do the same configuration and release on another server in a load balancing it is not working.

Does anyone have any clue on how to set this thing in a straight forward way in C#?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean? What is in the `Set-Cookie` header on the response? You can check using the guidance at https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: "But when I do the same configuration and release on another server in a load balancing it is not working" Sounds like either (a) the load balancer is intefering with your cookie headers (which is not unheard of), or (b) the domain under which the content is served from the LB does not match the domain of the cookie.

Answer (score 5):

You must install the December 10, 2019 (or later) cumulative update for the .NET Framework. [Search the Microsoft Support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/search?query=December%2010%202019%20Update%20for%20.NET%20Framework) to locate the appropriate update for your version of Windows and the .NET Framework.

Without the update, ASP.NET will **never** add the SameSite=None attribute to response cookies.

With the update, ASP.NET will add the SameSite=None attribute to response cookies if you explicitly set [HttpCookie.SameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.samesite?view=netframework-4.8) to SameSiteMode.None or if you set the `<httpCookies sameSite="None">` attribute in Web.config. The update also changes the default SameSite mode to Lax for ASP.NET forms authentication and session cookies. To change them back to None, set the `<forms cookieSameSite="None">` and `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None">` attributes in Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Solved such by adding the header directly:

`Response.Headers.Add("set-cookie", "mysessioncookie=theValue; path=/; SameSite=Strict")`